# How to bind a property in the view model to a Label.Content within a dictionary.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5, resourcedictionary

I have an WPF MVVM app.

I have a WPF dictionary.xaml in which I have below style:

```
<Style x:Key="myPopupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Path x:Name="Container"
                              Data="M8,7.41 L15.415,0 L22.83,7.41 L224,7.41 L224,130 L0,130 L0,7.41 L8,7.41"
                              Fill="White"
                              Stroke="#BEBEBE">
                        </Path>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=myText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,10,5,5"
                                       MaxHeight="130"
                                       MaxWidth="224"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then in one of my views, I import the dictionary.xaml and I set this style on a popup:

`My View` (myView.xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="my.UI.Views.myView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:my.UI.ViewModels"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:my.UI"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- Dictionaries -->
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/myApps;component/Resources/Dictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

            <!-- SOME STUFF -->
            <Label x:Name="StatusText" Content="Hello!"/>
            <Popup AllowsTransparency="True"
                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=StatusText}"
                   Placement="Bottom">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=myTooltip, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource myPopupStyle}"/>
            <Popup>

            <!-- MORE STUFF --->

</Window>
```

**My view model** (myViewModel.cs) - Only showing relevant parts for this post -:

```
public class myViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public myViewModel()
    {}

    public string myText
    {
            get => this._myText;

            set
            {
                if (this._myText!= value)
                {
                    this._myText= value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
    }

    public string myTooltip
    {
            get => this._myTooltip;

            set
            {
                if (this._myTooltip!= value)
                {
                    this._myTooltip= value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
    }

    public string _myText;
    public string _myTooltip;
}
```

In my view model I have a property called myText which I am binding to the Label within the style defined in the dictionary.xaml.

When I run it, it is not working, below error is thrown:

> Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being
> processed.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.InvalidOperationException: Dispatcher processing has been
> suspended, but messages are still being processed.    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
> msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
> IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

So how can I bind the property myText which is in my view model to the Label defined within the style in the dictionary.xaml?

Comment: 1) It would be interesting to know the exact error message and how/where the myText property is defined. Given that the Conten of the ContentControl is your view model class that exposes the myText property, your binding should work. But the Content is bound to a myTooltip property, which doesn't seem to be the view model class. In this case the binding would fail. 2) myText must raise PropertyChanged and the view model class  must implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: 3) You should not bind a string to the Label.Content property as it results in bad performance. Since string is immutable, changing the Label.Content value (the source string) will result in forcing teh Label to render/construct the content from scratch instead of updating it. You should prefer a TextBlock which is optimized to handle strings.

Comment: @BionicCode  See my update. 1) myText is defined in the view model class. myTooltip property is another property which I use to bind to popup in the view. But binding of myTooltip is working perfectly. My problem is when I try to bind myText to the label in the dictionary.xaml which I import in the view. 2) myText is a property defined in the view model class and this class inherits from ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. 3) Ok, thanks, i will change label into textblock, no problem. But now this is not my problem. I agree that using label will results in bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. I was trying to explain in my comment that your binding inside the `Popup` is wrong. The `ContentControl.Content` is currently bound to `myViewModel.myTooltip`, which is a `string`.
   Then the `ContententControl.ContentTemplate` is set to a `DataTemplate` that targets the wrong data type (`myViewModel`). The actual data type per binding is a `string` (the `myTolltip` value).
   In other words, the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` (`ContententControl.ContentTemplate`) is the object that is assigned to the `ContententControl.Content` property.

   To fix your issue, the `ContentControl.Content` must reference the `myViewModel` instance (the current `DataContext`). You also could add another `TextBlock` to the `DataTemplate` in order to display the `myTooltip` value:

```xml
<Popup>
  
  <!-- Assign the myViewModel to the Content property,
       so that the type of the DataTemplate matches the Content -->
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource myPopupStyle}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myViewModel}">
        <Border>
          <Grid>
            <Path />

            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding myText}" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding myTolltip}" />
            </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
  </ContentControl>
</Popup>
```

2. `BindingMode.OneWay` is the default. It's redundant to set this mode explicitly.
3. Fields should never be `public`. Instead you are advised to use properties. Defining the backing field of a property `public` would allow to bypass the property, which could lead to unexpected side effects. The only exception are event fields. They are treated specially by the compiler (e.g. the compiler will create a property and guards against public invocation)
4. You should not bind a `string` to the `Label.Content` property as it results in bad performance. Since `string` is immutable, changing the `Label.Content` value (the source `string`) will force the `Label` to reconstruct the content from scratch (e.g. apply a complete new template) instead of updating it.
   You should prefer a `TextBlock` which is optimized to handle `string` more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you very  much. Points 2, 3 and 4 I totally agree. 3 was a mistake typing in the post. Regarding 1, yep I understand, but I wanted to have that Style within a resource dictionary (dictionary.xaml) separated because I want to use that style in other views and objects (from the same or different view) so I avoid to type that piece of code every time for all objects in the same view or in different views. So is it possible to keep that style in a separated dictionary and import it to the views and use it?

Comment: ...  i mean, is there some way to bind the correct datacontext to the style within the dictionary.xaml so i can use it in all the views i have?

Comment: I inlined the ContentTemplate to keep the example compact. You can of course move it to a resource dictionary. A DataTemplate always targets a particular type. You can't make it work with every type. The bindings didn't allow this (except all types define the same properties). You must create a dedicated DataTemplate for every type.